# JavaScript Capture handled Errors

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a solution in which I can capture all the errors(handled/unhandled) logged in the browser console.

I am aware about `window.onerror` and also `window.addeventlistener('error', function(){})`.

The above code captures only unhandled errors. I need to capture handled errors also.

> **For example:**

```
function foo() {
  var x = null;
  try {
    x.a = "";
  } catch (e) {
    //Exception will be digested here.
  }

  var y = null
  y.b = "";
}

window.onerror = function() {
  //Write logic for the errors logged in console.
}

foo();
```

In the above example `try catch` is there, so I will get error only for variable `y` not `x`.

Is there any way to listen/capture the `catch` block?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#The_finally_clause

Comment: You can do that when using a debugger. But not from JS itself. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you really want to, you can throw after your catch with a custom error, which will be passed to window.onerror. Example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/L29jv5fv/ What are you trying to do?

Comment: @AlbertoRivera agreed, this can be achieved by throwing error. But I  have a scenario where I need to digest the exception.

Comment: @Ankur How about calling the function directly inside the catch? `catch (e) {window.onerror('test',null,null,null,'custom');}` However, please reconsider your approach. This seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling window.onerror manually. However, please reconsider changing your approach. This is extremely dirty.

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
  if (error === 'custom') {
   console.log("Handled error logged");
   return true;
  }
  console.log("unhandled error")
  return false;
};
```

Example try/catch

```
var myalert = function() {
  try {
    console.log(f);
  } catch (e) {
    window.onerror('test',null,null,null,'custom');
  }
  console.log("Gets here");
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/L29jv5fv/2/

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that if an exception is caught, then it isn't a problem because your code knows how to deal with it.

In other programming languages like Java it's always good practise to only catch exceptions you can handle, and to throw everything else further up the chain and/or map to a different exception that may be more useful further up the call stack.

For example:

```
function foo() {
  var x = null;
  try {
    x.a = "";
  } catch (e) {
    //Exception will be digested here.
    console.log("I am writing code here but still don't know how to proceed");
    throw new CustomError("Something was wrong");
  }

  var y = null
  y.b = "";
}
```